# print issues,when i print the main part, there is always a margin in the left,can i print main part occupied the full page

Tags: html, css

**can i print the main part without left blank? thanks**

i'm trying to print the main part,but i don't need the left margin when i right click and print.

does anyone encounter this print issue and please help me with this, thanks

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @media print {
      .header,
      .nav {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .header {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: brown;
    }
    
    .nav {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 50px;
      width: 150px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .main {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 150px;
      background-color: blueviolet;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">1</div>
  <div class="nav">2</div>
  <div class="main">33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You set the position    `left: 150px; `quick fix would be just reduce it but I would say use for the layout something like css grid

Answer (score 1):

You are setting here in `.main{left: 150px;}` the margin to the edge. As quick fix you can just reduce its value.

For Grid Based layouts CSS has something called **CSS-Grid**. There you can define your own grid means specify the amount of column and rows and also its size. Then place your elements inside this grid.

This would be a good choice for your task.
Here you can read more

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

I made you an example to demonstrate how it works
You have and wrapper element here the div with the class name *container* where you define your grid like
How many Columns? How many rows? Which size has each row and each column.

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
grid-template-rows: 50px 500px;
```

Then inside your elements you can set its position for example second row first column

```
.nav {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 500px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: brown;
}

.nav {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.innerMain {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">1</div>
    <div class="nav">2</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="innerMain">33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```